# Is there a way to calculate the blast radius of an explosion starting with the yield of the bomb?

Tags: nuclear-physics, estimation, explosions

I am working on a video game with missile-oriented combat, and I would like to input a yield for a missile instead of directly giving it a blast radius, and have the program calculate the blast radius from the given yield. Therefore, I need an equation that can do that semi-realistically.

I am aware there will be differences in effect with different variables and that the blast is not perfectly spherical, but I would like something that I can use with a basic level of accuracy. [Nukemap on nuclearsecrecy.com](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/) has a calculator that will give the blast radius of custom yields of explosives, and I am looking for something similar. Thanks!

Comment: If you have the online calculator, I'd suggest just picking a few points in the range you care about, and graphing the radius versus yeild curve, and fit a relationship.  Without knowing about the specifics of bombs, I would bet that the relationship is something like (yield/blast volume) is constant, which gives you a relationship like $r = Cy^{1/3}$, but there are probably other considerations than something like that.

Comment: Yield will apply to success by overpressure. Anti-aircraft missiles don't succeed that way, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The blast radius of a bomb is function of the overpressure created by the blast wave that radiates outward. The link I'm attaching provides some information and a table of overpressure vs wind speed for several yields and a gauge of city destruction vs windspeed.
https://www.atomicarchive.com/science/effects/overpressure.html.